# Create a "mask" with text in SVG

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm currently trying to make a comment icon like below in svg, but with the space around the text as a cut hole in the speech bubble (not like the icon on the bottom).

I want to have a `<text>` element because I generate the svg dynamically with react.

Does someone know if it is possible ?

Thanks

[image: Commments SVG icons]

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I have a svg with a `<path>` for the bubble and a `<text>` for the counter; I did the border with multiple css text-shadow.

I tried to make a mask with the text, but It wasn't taking the border-width in consideration.

Comment: Do add that markup to the question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This filter uses a "green-screen" technique: you color the parts of your content that you want to discriminate among in separate primary colors - then use a color matrix to generate separate nodes containing just the content of each particular color. After you process the contents - at the end you use another color matrix to recolor the content into your final (single) desired color.

```html
    <svg width='400px' height='400px' viewBox='0 0 258 229' >
       <defs>
          <filter id="cut-out">
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 
                                                 0 0 0 0 0 
                                                 0 0 1 0 0 
                                                 -1 0 0 1 0"
                           result="just-blue"/>
             <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                                 0 0 0 0 0 
                                                 0 0 0 0 0 
                                                 0 0 -1 1 0"
        in="SourceGraphic" result="just-red"/>
            
         <feMorphology in="just-blue" operator="dilate" radius="3"/>  
        
            <feComposite operator="out" in="just-red"/>
            <feComposite operator="over" in2="just-blue"/>
            
         <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 .33
                                              0 0 0 0 .33
                                              0 0 0 0 .33
                                              0 0 0 1 0"/>   
            
         </filter>
      </defs>
      
      <g filter="url(#cut-out">
        <circle r="50" fill="red" cx="100" cy="100"/>
        <text x="110" y="140" stroke="none" fill="blue" font-size="70">3</text>
      </g>
            
    </svg>
```

Comment: Wonderful technique Very interesting. Did you come up with yourself or have solutions like that? I can ask you to give a link to the article, if it is .. I would be very grateful. The reference is not to the theory of matrices, but to this particular technique.

Comment: Developed it myself. I do a lot of filter stuff: https://codepen.io/mullany/  I've answered a few other questions using this green-screen technique - you can look at the other svg-filters tagged questions.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, many thanks ! I would not have find a solution by myself now I see this solution...